# Adverb as a modifier

Tags: syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases, adverbials

We have a sentence given below:

> I'll see you sometime in the afternoon.

In the above sentence, 'sometime' is an adverb, modifying the PP: 'in the afternoon.' The adverb 'sometime' can be expanded to the PP: 'at some time.' Now, if we rewrite the above sentence with this expanded form, we get:

> I'll see you at some time in the afternoon.

My question is: In the above sentence, can we say the PP: 'in the afternoon' is modifying the noun 'time', which in turn is modified by 'some,' finally forming the object of the preposition 'at'? This resulting PP then modifies the verb 'see'.
If the above analysis is possible, can we say that any sentence having an adverb that can be expanded to a PP, and that modifies a PP in that sentence, can be analysed in the same way as above?

Comment: Yes, except "sometime in the afternoon" modifies the sentence "I'll see you", not the verb.

Comment: Sorry, I should've said 'sometime in the afternoon' modifies the verb phrase 'see you' rather than saying it modifies only the verb 'see.'

Comment: @Greg Lee, thank you for your reply. You say 'except "sometime in the afternoon" modifies the sentence "I'll see you", not the verb.' So, is there any difference between a sentence modifier and a verb phrase modifier, especially when a sentence contains multiple verb phrases?

Comment: My answer mostly adopts McCawley's description of English clause adverbs in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**, where sentence adverbs are distinguished from V''-modifiers as I indicated.  However, there is the complication that some sentence adverbs can be converted to V' modifiers.  I'll have to refer you to McCawley for evidence.